# EventMachine WebSockets - Subscribe ws to EM channels vs Keeping sockets in collection

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I'm building a project which uses EM and WebSockets and involves broadcasting data to subscribed clients.

I'm wondering why would one prefer subscribing a websocket to a channel, like the following:

```
EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|

ws.onopen {
  sid = @channel.subscribe { |msg| ws.send msg }
  @channel.push "#{sid} connected!"

  ws.onmessage { |msg|
    @channel.push "<#{sid}>: #{msg}"
  }

  ws.onclose {
    @channel.unsubscribe(sid)
  }
}

end
```

Over adding each websocket to an array:

```
EM::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
ws.onopen {
  puts "Websocket connection opened"
  websocket_connections << ws
}
ws.onclose {
  puts "Websocket connection closed"
  websocket_connections.delete(ws)
}
end
```

and simply iterating over the entire array and make a similar `ws.send msg` call when appropriate (or the other way around).

Does the channel alternative has better optimisation for the entire non-blocking characteristics of EventMachine? (e.g. broadcast to some of the subscribed sockets in one time, and then continue with the others instead of sending all of them at once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EventMachine::Channel class is simply an abstraction that handles the iteration of a subscribers array. If you look at the Ruby source code for [EventMachine::Channel#push](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Channel.html#M000260), you see it is similar to what you propose:

```
def push(*items)
  items = items.dup
  EM.schedule { @subs.values.each { |s| items.each { |i| s.call i } } }
end
```

In fact, if you don't need to duplicate your items array, it is actually slower than manually iterating the list. However, I doubt that the performance impact is significant. EventMachine::Channel is simply an abstraction that makes managing lists of clients easier.